# JPanel gets smaller (a lot) after add to another JPanel

Tags: java

After I added my canvas (blue one) to canvas2 (green one), canvas got really small and I can't tell why. Help me! Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanel canvas = new JPanel();
    JPanel canvas2 = new JPanel();

    canvas.setBounds(40, 40, 200, 200);
    canvas.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    canvas2.setBounds(40, 40, 200, 200);
    canvas2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    canvas2.add(canvas);

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 600, 600);
    window.getContentPane().add(canvas2);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ignoring the container layout managers -- BorderLayout for the JFrame's contentPane and FlowLayout for the JPanel. The components added to these containers will be sized by these layout managers.

You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).

Answer (score 0):

`canvas` (blue `JPanel`) is completely empty. Therefore, it's `LayoutManager` is resizing it to the smallest possible size. It'll get bigger if you add some components to it. Alternatively, you could do

```
 canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
```

but this is generally a bad idea for several reasons.